Cookie session between FastAPI and Streamlit
I developed a web app with 2 services bundled in 2 docker containers. The frontend is developed with streamlit in python, the backend with fastAPI. Docker is set up in a Synology NAS with reverse proxies. The backend connects to a connected app of Salesforce with oAuth2 (web server flow to be able to connect each user) and it seems to work since I got result when I request the computational result directly backend in my browser (after connecting from streamlit). Nontheless, in Streamlit, it doesn't work : apparently, the cookie session is not correctly share between fastapi and streamlit since it's empty in streamlit.
Here is my streamlit code:
import streamlit as st
import requests
import pandas as pd

st.title('Salesforce Contacts Analysis')

# Lien pour démarrer l'authentication
login_url = "https://sf2.mydomain.synology.me/login"
st.markdown(f'<a href="{login_url}" target="_self">Connect to Salesforce</a>', unsafe_allow_html=True)

# Endpoint pour récupérer les données après authentication
session = requests.Session()  # Utiliser une session persistante pour gérer les cookies

# Vérifiez et affichez les cookies de session
st.write("Cookies before request:", session.cookies.get_dict())

response = session.get("https://sf2.mydomain.synology.me/contacts_count")

# Ajouter du débogage pour vérifier le contenu de la réponse
st.write("Response status code:", response.status_code)
st.write("Response headers:", response.headers)
st.write("Response text:", response.text)  # Afficher le contenu brut de la réponse

if response.status_code == 200:
    try:
        data = response.json()
        df = pd.DataFrame(list(data.items()), columns=["Year", "Number of Contacts"])
        st.write(df)
    except requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError as e:
        st.error(f"Failed to decode JSON: {e}")
        st.write("Raw response text:", response.text)  # Afficher le contenu brut de la réponse en cas d'erreur JSON
else:
    st.write("Please authenticate to view the data.")

And my backend in fastAPI:
import logging
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse, JSONResponse
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from datetime import datetime

# Configuration OAuth pour Salesforce Sandbox
CLIENT_ID = 'client_id'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'client_secret'
AUTH_URL = 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize'
TOKEN_URL = 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token'
REDIRECT_URI = 'https://sf2.mydomain.synology.me/callback'

# Générer un nom de fichier de log avec la date et l'heure
log_file = f"app_{datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')}.log"

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    # Configuration du logging
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levellevel)s - %(message)s')
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levellevel)s - %(message)s'))
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    logger.info("Starting up...")
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        logger.info("Shutting down...")
        for handler in logger.handlers:
            handler.close()
            logger.removeHandler(handler)

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

# Ajout du middleware de session
app.add_middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key='your-secret-key')

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info("Root endpoint hit")
    return {"message": "Welcome to the Salesforce OAuth2 integration"}

@app.get("/login")
async def login(request: Request):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info("Login endpoint hit")
    salesforce = OAuth2Session(CLIENT_ID, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)
    authorization_url, state = salesforce.authorization_url(AUTH_URL)
    request.session['oauth_state'] = state
    logger.info(f"Authorization URL: {authorization_url}")
    return RedirectResponse(authorization_url)

@app.get("/callback")
async def callback(request: Request):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info("Callback endpoint hit")
    try:
        state = request.session.get('oauth_state')
        salesforce = OAuth2Session(CLIENT_ID, state=state, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)
        token = salesforce.fetch_token(
            TOKEN_URL,
            client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
            authorization_response=str(request.url)
        )
        instance_url = token['instance_url']
        access_token = token['access_token']
        logger.info(f"Access token received: {access_token}")
        sf = Salesforce(instance_url=instance_url, session_id=access_token)

        # Stocker le token et l'instance_url dans la session
        request.session['token'] = access_token
        request.session['instance_url'] = instance_url
        
        return RedirectResponse(url="https://sf.mydomain.synology.me")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error in callback: {e}")
        return JSONResponse(content={"error": "Authentication failed", "details": str(e)}, status_code=400)

@app.get("/contacts_count")
async def contacts_count(request: Request):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info("Contacts count endpoint hit")
    try:
        token = request.session.get('token')
        instance_url = request.session.get('instance_url')
        
        if not token or not instance_url:
            logger.warning("No token or instance URL found in session")
            return RedirectResponse(url="/login")

        sf = Salesforce(instance_url=instance_url, session_id=token)
        contacts = sf.query_all("SELECT CreatedDate FROM Contact")
        year_count = {}

        for record in contacts['records']:
            year = record['CreatedDate'][:4]
            if year in year_count:
                year_count[year] += 1
            else:
                year_count[year] = 1
        
        logger.info(f"Contacts count by year: {year_count}")
        return JSONResponse(content=year_count)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error in contacts_count: {e}")
        return JSONResponse(content={"error": "Failed to retrieve contacts count", "details": str(e)}, status_code=500)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8007, ssl_keyfile="/app/certs/privkey.pem", ssl_certfile="/app/certs/cert.pem")

